# Python list sorting and indexing

Tags: python, deep-copy

I am having issue understanding and solving the following issue with lists, sorting and indexing.  Here is the code example:

```
import random as rdm
a=[]
for i in range(3):
    a.append([i,rdm.randint(-5,5)])
print a
b = sorted(a,key=lambda a:a[1])
print b
c = []
for j in range(len(b)):
    c.append(b[j])
print c
c[0][1] = 0
print a
print b
print c
```

Notice how changing one value of "C" changed "b" and "a".  How can I prevent it from happening?  In other words.  I do not want the values of "a" changed doesn't matter what happens to "b" or "c"

Comment: You are actually working with **lists** not **arrays**. It would make your question clearer if you rephrased it accordingly.

Comment: Title updated to lists rather than arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you write:

```
c.append(b[j])
```

You are adding into `c` a reference to the object `b[j]`.

If you want `b` and `c` to be independent of `a`, you must do a **deep copy** of the objects.

```
import copy
b = sorted (copy.deepcopy(a), lambda a : a[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`c.append(b[j])`
adds into `c` a reference to the object `b[j]`.

Thereafter, changing `c[j]` changes `b[j]`.
To avoid this, produce a copy, of `b[j]`, instead:
`c.append(copy.copy(b[j]))`
That requires `import copy`.

Indeed, Python tends to use references instead of copying elements, with certain exceptions (e.g., dict `.copy`, slicing, `sorted()`, dict `.get()` produce shallow copies). Would you write `d=b`, they would point to the same list (of lists). More: [Which commands/methods return a deepcopy / shallowcopy / original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913253/which-commands-methods-return-a-deepcopy-shallowcopy-original)

Would `b[j]` be a nested list instead of a list (e.g., `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`), its elements would be pointers  (references) to the lists on the next level (to the lists `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`). Then `copy.copy(b[j])` would produce a copy (`c[j]`) of that list of pointers. Changing `c[j]` would then not affect `b` but changing `c[j][k]` before that would affect `b[j][k]`.

Using `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy` always makes the result fully independent, as it recursively copies everything (also the nested lists).

As Storyteller wrote, also `b` depends on `a` unless you sort a copy of `a` instead of `a`:
`b = sorted(copy.deepcopy(a), lambda a : a[1])`.

Indeed, `sorted()` produces a shallow copy, so the second level is not copied but pointed to. For non-nested lists, shallow copy is enough for independence.